# [azerothcore]How to modify the conditions for entering an instance

Tags: azerothcore

Can allowing a solo player to enter a team instance be achieved through eluna?

```lua
function CheckMemberCount(event, player)
  return true  
end


RegisterPlayerEvent(42, OnCheckIfInGroup)

function OnCheckIfInGroup(event, player)
  return CheckMemberCount(event, player) 
end

RegisterInstanceEvent(1,CheckInstanceCondition)

function CheckInstanceCondition(event,player)
  return true
end
```

Comment: There are ways to solve your problem with the worldserver.conf or database. Eluna isn't suitable for this task, unless you want to jump through a lot of loops.